# Is it possible to use std::char_traits<char> in constant expressions before GCC 8?

Tags: c++, gcc, char-traits

According to the [GCC 8 Release Note](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/changes.html), it is now possible to use `std::char_traits<char>` and `std::char_traits<wchar_t>` in constant expressions:

> - Improved experimental support for C++17, including the following features:
>
>   - std::char_traits and std::char_traits<wchar_t> are usable in constant expressions.

What I understand here is you can't use `std::char_traits<char>` in constant expressions before GCC 8.

However, the following code compiles well with [GCC 7.5](https://godbolt.org/z/rMG5Pb):

```
#include <string_view>

int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view sv{""};
    constexpr std::size_t size = std::char_traits<char>::length(sv.data());

    return 0;
}
```

So, is it possible to use std::char_traits in constant expressions before GCC 8? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `Is it possible to use std::char_traits<char> in constant expressions before GCC 8?` Sure. It's just a class that is never going to be instantiated. The change log is simplifying a bit, and it is actually about the member functions of  `std::char_traits<char>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This improvement was [backported from mainline](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/53e7178da50ddf11bcb2fb8f2a15cb90844b9129). It is available in the gcc 7 line from 7.3 onwards.